Ansible hangs if you type your password incorrectly
I have an interesting problem when running ansible locally on ubuntu and debian (and probably others). If I type my password in incorrectly when using become_method: sudo, it hangs, seemingly indefinitely. If I use become_method: su, I get the authentication failure as expected. I've tried googling around but I just can't seem to find anything relevant. Here is a repro if anyone is interested in testing it as well:
ansible localhost -m command -a whoami --become --ask-become-pass --become-method sudo # hangs
ansible localhost -m command -a whoami --become --ask-become-pass --become-method su   # errors as expected

Does anyone know why this is happening and if it is expected behavior?
I tried running it with increased verbosity (-vvv) and I believe it's hanging by asking for the password again (under the covers).
Here's the log line when it hangs:
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'sudo -H -S -p "[sudo via ansible, key=pncrrupxbnzwoycrlrmdgzczawqoeyzg] password:" -u root /bin/sh -c '"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-pncrrupxbnzwoycrlrmdgzczawqoeyzg ; /home/user/.local/pipx/venvs/ansible/bin/python /home/user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1726279006.3582602-16320-275838986576525/AnsiballZ_command.py'"'"' && sleep 0'

